# live stream saved or not

Tags: webvideos, live-recording

Trying to work out if you upload a live stream if it is routed and just played or if it saves into a folder. So for example if you set up a webcam 24 hours and relay that online if that just broadcasts and you then can configure options to save, otherwise it just plays? It would take up a lot of space if were saving to server so trying to be clear on it. Any help to understand greatly appreciated.

Comment: A little more detailed is needed here to help you with your problem. What are you doing exactly and what do you want to achieve? What software is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the configuration and choice of streaming server.  You can generally configure stream servers to either record live streams or simply relay them.

Comment: Right so I can safely say I am only relaying the stream at present, thanks.